# Generate bash script with .tar.gz payload

Tags: bash, character-encoding, binary

I want to use a python3 script to generate a 'self-extracting' bash script which has an embedded .tar.gz archive as payload.

In bash I would simply do something like this:

```
printf "#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  PAYLOAD_LINE=\`awk '/^__PAYLOAD_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' \$0\`                                                                                                                                                          
  tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar -xvz                                                                                                                                                                                             
  #script that does something with the unpacked payload                                                                                                                                                                                    
  exit 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  __PAYLOAD_BELOW__\n" > "tmpfile"

cat "tmpfile" "payload.tar.gz" > "myscript.sh"
```

What I tried in python is this:

```
with open('myscript.sh','wb') as script:                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    for line in open(payload.tar.gz, 'rb'):                                                                                                                                                                                              
        script.write(line)
```

I can untar the resulting file manually with `cat myscript.sh | tar -xvz`

To add the bash script part (`PAYLOAD_LINE= .... __PAYLOAD_BELOW__\n"`), is there a more elegant way than to open `myscript.sh` a second time, but not in binary (`'wb'`) mode?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I just have to convert the string to bytes, before writing it to the file, so I don't have to open it twice.

```
script_header = """#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PAYLOAD_LINE=\`awk '/^__PAYLOAD_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' \$0\`                                                                                                                                                          
tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar -xvz"""     

with open('myscript.sh','wb') as script:
    script.write(bytes(script_header + '\n', 'utf-8'))
    for line in open(payload.tar.gz, 'rb'):                                                                                                                                                                                              
        script.write(line)
```